# How do I rotate a vector 90 degrees in a random direction?

Tags: geometry, vectors, rotations

I'm building a tree generator and I'm at the point where I want to have sub branches branch off at right angles off the current branch, in random directions. I have a 3D vector defining the direction of the current branch but I can't for the life of me figure out how to transform that to a direction for the sub branch.

I have googled the problem and also searched here, but I can only find related problems and apparently I'm just not smart enough to figure out how to apply them to my problem.

So what needs to happen, given a certain 3D vector *v*, which can be pointing in any direction:

1. Rotate *v* 90 degrees in some direction such that it ends up on the plane it defines; call that *v'*
2. Rotate *v'* an arbitrary amount on that plane; in other words around the axis defined by *v*

Or put more simply:

1. Rotate *v* 90 degrees in a random direction

I'm doing this in Java; the vector is stored in a javax.vecmath.Vector3f. I know about affine transforms, but as far as I understand they rotate around global axes, and I need to rotate my vector around the local axes defined by itself, if that makes sense.

Can someone hand hold me through this problem?

Comment: rotate by 90 degrees clockwise and anti-clockwise in the same plane as that of your vector, and then "twist" it out the plane by a random amount. I'll type out a longer answer when I have the time

Comment: @SiddharthBhat Thanks! :) I'm looking forward to it as I don't yet understand how to achieve what you propose.

Comment: if $\left(\begin{matrix}a\\b\\c\end{matrix}\right)$ is your current direction, and $\left(\begin{matrix}p\\q\\r\end{matrix}\right)$ is the new perpendicular direction, then $ap+bq+cr=0$ where you can choose two of $p,q,r$ randomly and the third is thereby determined. Does that help?

Comment: @DavidQuinn I'm not sure. That's the kind of math I understand, but I would also like the new vector to have the same length as the original and that seems hard with this, or not? I can't just pick two random values for p and q and then determine r as then the new vector might be perpendicular to the old one, but it will have a random length, right? I guess I could then adjust the length pretty easily though.

Comment: @DavidQuinn Thinking about it more, and to test my understanding: is it true that I would have to make sure p and q are randomly picked from a circular area if I want to make sure that every angle is equally likely?

Comment: yes you could normalize the new vector and adjust the length accordingly

Comment: @DavidQuinn - I wrote down your method more formally as an answer - It's much simpler than what I have in mind. I hope you don't mind!

Comment: @SiddharthBhat: no problem at all!

Comment: @PepijnSchmitz - any chance you're not satisfied with the answer? I was hoping you'd accept it if you found it useful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the branch vector $\vec b = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$, then any vector perpendicular to it , say $\vec p = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$ will have dot product $0$.

So,

$$
\vec b . \vec p = x_0x_1 + y_0y_1 + z_0z_1  = \vec0 \\\text{dot product is zero as they are perpendicular}
$$pick any $x_1, y_1$ you prefer, and set $z_1$ as

$$z_1 = - \frac{\left (x_0 x_1 + y_0 y_1\right)}{ z_0}$$

That seems to be the simplest approach to get "random" branches.

If you want to control the length of the vector, then you can always normalize your obtained vector $\vec p$ and get the result vector $\vec r$ by using

$$
\vec r = len \times\frac{\vec p}{\left | \vec p\right| } 
$$

where $len$ is the desired length of the vector.

If $z_0$ is $0$, then you'll get a singularity when you try to divide by $z_0$.

However, since $z_0$ is $0$, it does not impact the dot product at all, and therefore we can pick *any* $z_1$ we want to.

Solve for $y_1$ by picking some $x_1$, and then allowing $z_1$ to be "free" (that is, you can pick any $z_1 \in \mathbb{R}$). However, in doing so, you'll face a problem if $y_0$ is $0$ as well.

If both $z_0 = y_0 = 0$, then, you're forced to set $x_1 = 0$ (to maintain the dot product as $0$ for perpendicularity) while having $y_1, z_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ (that is, they are free).

Comment: an adjustment needs to be made in your formula if $z_0=0$

Comment: fixed, thanks! I advised OP to simply create another random vector, since it is highly unlikely that a PRNG will generate a $0$ twice in a row

Comment: @SiddharthBhat Thanks! I have two questions, mostly to test my understanding: firstly, you say to generate another random vector if _z0_ is 0, but _z0_ is a fixed component of the original vector so that won't help, right? It seems the only option I have if _z0_ is 0 is to solve for _x1_ or _y1_ (they can't _all_ be zero but any two of them might be).

Comment: Ah, right. That slipped my mind. Yes, you're right, that's something I messed up. If $z_0$ is $0$, then you can solve for $x_1$, $y_1$ while picking any $z_1$ you want. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: And secondly: do I understand correctly that if I want every angle to be equally likely I need to pick _x1_ and _y1_ to be a random point from a circular area? If it's a square area (as in if I just randomly pick two values from some range) then the corners of the square will be overrepresented, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right - you'll need to pick the components in a circle. One way to do this is to pick a $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)$ and then set $x = \cos \theta, y = \sin \theta$ to get points on the unit circle.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat Thinking about it even more, it shouldn't even be a circle, but an ellipse which is the the projection of the circle on the plane x,y. This is turning out to be harder than I thought. ;) Is there another way to ensure every angle will be equally likely?

Comment: You could do this other thing where you pick vectors from a 3-D sphere, and then force them to become orthogonal from the original vector by using an orthogonalization process such as [Gram Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). Reference to [picking points from a sphere](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html)

Comment: However, I'm not convinced that a uniform $(x, y)$ over the circle will not work. Why would it not?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat I think that was my mistake. Thanks, I'll try this solution and most likely accept your answer shortly!

Comment: @PepijnSchmitz - I'm assuming the solution worked since you green-ticked the answer?

Comment: I implemented this and it's working fine, thanks! Also thanks to @DavidQuinn of course. I solved the _z0_ = 0 problem by just solving for _y1_ in that case, or _x1_ if both _z0_ and _y0_ are 0.

Answer (score 2):

Let ${\bf u}$ be the unit vector in ${\mathbb R}^3$ giving the forward direction of the current branch, ending at the point ${\bf p}$. This branch emanated from a previous point ${\bf p}'$, and there was a unit vector ${\bf u}'$ defining the previous branch ending at ${\bf p}'.$ We shall need this vector for the next step!

Note that ${\bf u}'\perp{\bf u}$.  The pair ${\bf u}'$, ${\bf u}$ is supplemented by ${\bf v}:={\bf u}'\times {\bf u}$ to an orthonormal basis of ${\mathbb R}^3$ containing ${\bf u}$ as a member. It follows that ${\bf u}'$ and ${\bf v}$ are orthogonal unit vectors in the plane orthogonal to ${\bf u}$.

In order to obtain a random unit vector ${\bf w}$ in this plane generate a uniformly distributed $\phi\in[0,2\pi]$ and put
$${\bf w}:=\cos\phi\,{\bf u}'+\sin\phi\,{\bf v}\ .$$
Note that the vector ${\bf w}$ constructed in this way  depends only on ${\bf u}$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry but I don't know enough about this kind of math to be able to follow your answer. Do you think you could make it clearer for a geometry math newb? Is it materially different than Siddarth/David's answer?

Comment: @PepijnSchmitz: I'm doing standard vector geometry in ${\mathbb R}^3$. The essential idea is to store the second last branch vector. This allows to obtain explicit orthogonal generators of the orthogonal plane without danger of vanishing denominators. – Siddarth/David's solution contains no random elements and is heavily reliant on accidental coordinate values.

Comment: I think I understand, but I don't think I can use this method as my branches aren't necessarily straight, so when they spawn a sub branch they are no longer necessarily perpendicular to the branch from which they themselves branched off. It's an interesting alternative though, thanks.